# What's the difference between Whey Isolate and Whey Concentrate in shakes?

Tags: protein, nutrition

What's the difference? I'm looking at shake options and some contain whey isolate, some contain whey concentrate and some both.

Comment: This question was asked long before the scope was shifted to exclude nutrition except in the context of a workout program. Please do not use it as an example of acceptable questions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main difference is in the "purity", how much lactose and fat is left with the protein after filtering. Whey isolate usually contains around 90% protein and whey concentrate is more like 70-85%.

If you have trouble digesting the lactose or are trying to minimize carbohydrate content, then whey isolate would be a good choice. Otherwise, it probably doesn't matter; just pick the concentrate since it's cheaper in terms of protein grams/dollar.