# Weight-gain through Protein shakes

Tags: protein, weight-gain, health, protein-shakes

Well I do very little working out because I have a busy schedule with working and school...every now and then I'll try to walk around the neighborhood for 40 minutes,but this is every blue moon I'm 5'3 and 112 pounds. Very very skinny.. I want to gain some weight and every time I look up how to gain weight, protein shakes pop up...I just want to look healthy and maybe gain at least 6 to 8 pounds... So is this the right route?

Comment: Protein shakes don't get you in shape. Working out does.

Comment: @Alec Well, playing devil's advocate, he didn't mention getting in shape. He just wants to gain some pounds and look bigger :)

Answer (score 1):

No. Protein shakes will not make you gain weight alone. In order to gain weight, you have to consume more calories, protein by itself does nothing for weight gain. If you want to gain weight from muscle, you have to lift weights while eating enough calories and protein. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

[Protein shakes are just protein. In a shake.](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/4066/1771) They won't magically help you gain weight. To gain weight, you need to [lift weights and eat a lot](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771). Protein shakes don't have to be part of it at all.

The reason protein shakes come up when you search for weight gain solutions is because people can make money selling you protein shakes. They make money by saying their product will fix your problem. Their product will not fix your problem. These salespeople are parasites trying to distract you from the hard work of lifting heavy weight and eating a lot of food. Don't let their money-grabbing lies fool you: protein shakes are the least important part of weight gain.

Comment: Well what's a good way to gain weight, I'm convinced that I have a fast metabolism because there are days when I can eat made crazy and consume more calories than I need and I see no type of results . I have little to nothing fat or muscle... I just want to look healthy.... Also I'm 17.. People always say I could go for 12.

Comment: @Amaris Click the second link in my answer. Here it is again: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle/6836#6836